# All my Folder and Application icons disappeared in Finder

Tags: finder, macos, dock, icon

I've been using Yosemite happily since it was released, but yesterday all my icons disappeared. See the attached screenshots. My dock only shows the icon for the Finder, and within Finder itself none of the icons for applications or folders show up. The only thing that seems to work is thumbnail previews for things like Word documents, PDFs and image files.

[image]
[image]

These are some things I tried already:

- rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/* and sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/*
- rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db && killall -HUP Finder Dock
- rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
- I tried booting in Safe Mode, the problem persists there.
- I even tried **reinstalling the OS** and for some reason the problem still exists.
- Unfortunately I can't log in as a different user, this is a company mac and my login is our network login.

I'm at a total loss. What can I do? The only thing I can think of that I changed recently was uninstalling an app called Bitcasa by manually removing some of its application files, including /Applications/Bitcasa.app, ~/Library/Preferences/com.bitcasa, ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.bitcasa.Bitcasa.plist, ~/Library/ScriptingAdditions/BitcasaIntegration.osax, ~/Library/Caches/com.bitcasa.Bitcasa, and ~/Library/Application Support/com.bitcasa.Bitcasa.

Comment: If after reinstalling the OS the problem persist, then it is usually your preferences settings, since those do not get changed when reinstalling.

Comment: Is there a way to reset preferences to default?

Comment: for what is worth, run disk permission repair for now. and try to log in as different user to check that.

Comment: I just checked the instructions for Bitcasa removal here https://support.bitcasa.com/hc/en-us/articles/202216558-How-to-Uninstall-Bitcasa-Mac- and assume you did to?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't log in as a different user, this is a company mac and my login is our network login.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem--not with icons in the dock--but Illustrator icons in Finder list view would just display as blank white icons instead of the Illustrator CC icons.  Using the info in this thread, I showed all hidden files.  This can be done using the XtraFinder app.  Once all hidden files were shown, I went to the path below and moved the store.index file to the desktop and logged out and logged back in.  The store.index file re-created itself and all of my Illustrator icons were back.  You can delete the one on the desktop and empty the trash before once again hiding all the hidden files through XtraFinder.  Solved!

`HD/private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.iconservices/store.index`

The asterisks represent random folder names that are different for each computer.  The last asterisk may have more than one folder.  Find the C folder that is not locked.

Comment: Your solution has resolved my problem. Thank you :).

Answer (score -1):

The icon caches in OS X are stored under `/private/var/folders`. To clear them try the following commands in a Terminal window.

```
sudo rm /private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.dock.iconcache
sudo rm -rf /private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.iconservices
killall Dock
killall Finder
```

Hopefully you should then find your icons restored.

Comment: It's unadvisable to remove the folders for all users (including root and other system files) in that manner.

Comment: What would you recommend instead? I know one person's anecdotal evidence isn't worth much, but I've done this a few times over the years without any ill effects. The system seems to quite happily regenerate the files/folders as it needs them.

Comment: This was one of the things I tried yesterday as well, didn't have any affect.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, I would first do "ls -lFad /var/folders/*/*" in order to isolate the one directory that is owned by the user experiencing trouble.  Removing the contents of just that folder is less harmful.  I would also recommend to do this while logged in as a different user.  As you said, the folders are usually regenerated as required, but it's better to not tempt fate by removing system files, and not to remove another user's files.  For a single-user system this is not an issue, but, for multi-user systems, it would be rude to remove person B's files to solve person A's trouble.

Comment: Interesting, but I assume you are aware that the 'C' in the paths above signifies "Cache". The folder actually used to be called "-Caches-" in previous versions. Surely something very strange would have to happen for anything irreplaceable to end up in one of these folders?

Comment: Yes -- I actually missed that the first time.  My head gets queasy whenever I see "sudo", "rm" and "*" on the same line anywhere.  :-)

Comment: I know that feeling. I'm normally the one advising caution. Telling people to never delete thing; just rename them.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me (on 10.10.5) what to logout, login as a different user, and then log back in as me.

Comment: The OP has stated that he/she cannot log into a different user account and has already tried rebooting the computer.